Adding 3D points to the current 3D Pose for visualization
I have 3D measurement points that I used python to calculate, and exported them to json, those 3D Points actually come from a SMPL Mesh mesurment. As shown here.

So I'm trying to map these points into your mediapipe pose estimation, and visualize them.
First I get mediapipe points from the callback,
image
then I do Singular Value Decomposition between MediaPipe 3D Pose and SMPL Measurment Points.
But I can't get at least for first trial the MediaPipe Points visualization onto the Video Correctly as a first step for the alignment.
The mediapipe points are red spheres

Whole code:
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Accord.Math;
using Vector3 = Accord.Math.Vector3;

public class SMPLMediaPipeMapper : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextAsset smplDataJson;
    private JObject smplData;
    private Vector3[] smplJoints;
    private Dictionary<int, int> smplToMediaPipeMapping;
    private Dictionary<string, Vector3> measurementPoints;
    public Camera mainCamera;
    public Vector3[] mediaPipeKeypoints;
    public float mediaPipeToSMPLScale = 1f;
    public GameObject smplSphere;
    public GameObject mediaSphere;
    public GameObject alignedSphere;

    private bool measurementPointsInstantiated = false;

    void Start()
    {
        mainCamera = Camera.main;
        LoadSMPLData();
    }

    void LoadSMPLData()
    {
        smplData = JObject.Parse(smplDataJson.text);
        var jointsValues = smplData["smpl_joints"].ToObject<List<List<float>>>();
        smplJoints = jointsValues.Select(j => new Vector3(j[0], j[1], j[2])).ToArray();
        smplToMediaPipeMapping = smplData["smpl_to_mediapipe_mapping"].ToObject<Dictionary<int, int>>();
        measurementPoints = smplData["measurement_points"]
            .ToObject<Dictionary<string, List<float>>>()
            .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => new Vector3(-1.0f * kvp.Value[0], -1.0f * kvp.Value[1], -1.0f * kvp.Value[2]));
    }

    public static Vector3[] AlignPoints(Vector3[] mediaPipeKeypoints, Dictionary<string, Vector3> measurementPoints)
    {
        // Mapping the MediaPipe landmarks to measurement points
        Dictionary<int, string> mediaPipeToMeasurements = new Dictionary<int, string>
        {
            { 11, "LEFT_SHOULDER" },
            { 12, "RIGHT_SHOULDER" },
            { 15, "LEFT_WRIST" },
            { 16, "RIGHT_WRIST" },
            { 23, "LOW_LEFT_HIP" },
            { 24, "INSEAM_POINT" },  // Approximation for right hip
            { 25, "LEFT_THIGH" },    // Approximation for left knee
            { 27, "LEFT_ANKLE" },
            { 28, "RIGHT_ANKLE" },
            { 29, "LEFT_HEEL" },
            { 30, "RIGHT_HEEL" }
        };

        // Prepare lists for aligned points
        List<Vector3> pointsA = new List<Vector3>();  // MediaPipe points
        List<Vector3> pointsB = new List<Vector3>();  // Measurement points

        // Align the measurement points to the corresponding MediaPipe landmarks
        foreach (var map in mediaPipeToMeasurements)
        {
            int mediaPipeIndex = map.Key;
            string measurementKey = map.Value;

            // Make sure the measurement exists in the dictionary
            if (measurementPoints.ContainsKey(measurementKey) && mediaPipeIndex < mediaPipeKeypoints.Length)
            {
                pointsA.Add(mediaPipeKeypoints[mediaPipeIndex]);        // MediaPipe point
                pointsB.Add(measurementPoints[measurementKey]);  // Corresponding measurement point
            }
        }

        // Convert the matched points to arrays
        Vector3[] setA = pointsA.ToArray();
        Vector3[] setB = pointsB.ToArray();

        // Perform alignment using Procrustes or similar alignment method
        return AlignPointsUsingProcrustes(setA, setB, mediaPipeKeypoints, measurementPoints);
    }

    public static Vector3[] AlignPointsUsingProcrustes(Vector3[] setA, Vector3[] setB, Vector3[] fullMediaPipeKeypoints, Dictionary<string, Vector3> fullMeasurementPoints)
    {
        // Compute centroids for both sets
        Vector3 centroidA = ComputeCentroid(setA);
        Vector3 centroidB = ComputeCentroid(setB);

        // Center the points by subtracting centroids
        var centeredA = setA.Select(p => p - centroidA).ToArray();
        var centeredB = setB.Select(p => p - centroidB).ToArray();

        // Compute the rotation matrix using the centered points
        var rotationMatrix = ComputeRotationMatrix(centeredA, centeredB);

        // Apply the rotation to all measurement points (even those that were not mapped)
        return fullMeasurementPoints.Values
            .Select(p => ApplyRotation(p - centroidB, rotationMatrix) + centroidA)
            .ToArray();
    }

    public void UpdateMediaPipeKeypoints(Vector3[] newKeypoints)
    {
        if (measurementPointsInstantiated)
            return;

        if (newKeypoints.Length != 33)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Expected 33 MediaPipe keypoints");
            return;
        }
        mediaPipeKeypoints = newKeypoints;

        Vector3[] alignedPoints = AlignPoints(mediaPipeKeypoints, measurementPoints);
        measurementPointsInstantiated = true;

        VisualizeMappedKeypoints(alignedPoints);
    }

    public static Vector3 ComputeCentroid(Vector3[] points)
    {
        Vector3 sum = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        foreach (var point in points)
        {
            sum += point;
        }
        return sum / points.Length;
    }

    public static double[,] ComputeRotationMatrix(Vector3[] setA, Vector3[] setB)
    {
        // Compute the covariance matrix
        double[,] covarianceMatrix = new double[3, 3];
        for (int i = 0; i < setA.Length; i++)
        {
            covarianceMatrix[0, 0] += setA[i].X * setB[i].X;
            covarianceMatrix[0, 1] += setA[i].X * setB[i].Y;
            covarianceMatrix[0, 2] += setA[i].X * setB[i].Z;
            covarianceMatrix[1, 0] += setA[i].Y * setB[i].X;
            covarianceMatrix[1, 1] += setA[i].Y * setB[i].Y;
            covarianceMatrix[1, 2] += setA[i].Y * setB[i].Z;
            covarianceMatrix[2, 0] += setA[i].Z * setB[i].X;
            covarianceMatrix[2, 1] += setA[i].Z * setB[i].Y;
            covarianceMatrix[2, 2] += setA[i].Z * setB[i].Z;
        }

        // Perform SVD on the covariance matrix
        var svd = new Accord.Math.Decompositions.SingularValueDecomposition(covarianceMatrix);
        var u = svd.LeftSingularVectors;
        var vt = svd.RightSingularVectors;

        // Compute the rotation matrix as U * Vt
        var rotationMatrix = Accord.Math.Matrix.Dot(u, vt.Transpose());

        return rotationMatrix;
    }

    public static Vector3 ApplyRotation(Vector3 point, double[,] rotationMatrix)
    {
        double X = rotationMatrix[0, 0] * point.X + rotationMatrix[0, 1] * point.Y + rotationMatrix[0, 2] * point.Z;
        double Y = rotationMatrix[1, 0] * point.X + rotationMatrix[1, 1] * point.Y + rotationMatrix[1, 2] * point.Z;
        double Z = rotationMatrix[2, 0] * point.X + rotationMatrix[2, 1] * point.Y + rotationMatrix[2, 2] * point.Z;
        return new Vector3((float)X, (float)Y, (float)Z);
    }

    UnityEngine.Vector3 TransformPoint(UnityEngine.Matrix4x4 transformationMatrix, UnityEngine.Vector3 point, bool inverse = false)
    {
        return inverse
            ? transformationMatrix.inverse.MultiplyPoint3x4(point)
            : transformationMatrix.MultiplyPoint3x4(point);
    }

    public void VisualizeMappedKeypoints(Vector3[] alignedPoints)
    {
        UnityMainThreadDispatcher.Enqueue(() =>
        {
            UnityEngine.Matrix4x4 transformationMatrix = UnityEngine.Matrix4x4.identity;

            // Define MediaPipe keypoint names
            string[] mediaPipeNames = new string[]
            {
                "Nose",
                "Left Eye (Inner)",
                "Left Eye",
                "Left Eye (Outer)",
                "Right Eye (Inner)",
                "Right Eye",
                "Right Eye (Outer)",
                "Left Ear",
                "Right Ear",
                "Mouth (Left)",
                "Mouth (Right)",
                "Left Shoulder",
                "Right Shoulder",
                "Left Elbow",
                "Right Elbow",
                "Left Wrist",
                "Right Wrist",
                "Left Pinky",
                "Right Pinky",
                "Left Index",
                "Right Index",
                "Left Thumb",
                "Right Thumb",
                "Left Hip",
                "Right Hip",
                "Left Knee",
                "Right Knee",
                "Left Ankle",
                "Right Ankle",
                "Left Heel",
                "Right Heel",
                "Left Foot Index",
                "Right Foot Index"
            };

            // Visualize MediaPipe keypoints
            for (int i = 0; i < mediaPipeKeypoints.Length; i++)
            {
                if (mediaPipeKeypoints[i].Y < 0) continue; // Skip invisible points
                var point = mediaPipeKeypoints[i];
                CreateSphereAtPoint(point, mediaSphere, mediaPipeNames[i]);
            }
            // Visualize aligned measurement points
            foreach (var alignedPoint in alignedPoints)
            {
                CreateSphereAtPoint(alignedPoint, alignedSphere, "AlignedMeasurementPoint");
            }
            // Visualize measurement points
            foreach (var measurement in measurementPoints)
            {
                CreateSphereAtPoint(measurement.Value, smplSphere, measurement.Key);
            }
        });
    }

    void CreateSphereAtPoint(Vector3 point, GameObject spherePrefab, string name)
    {
        var sphere = Instantiate(spherePrefab, new UnityEngine.Vector3(point.X, point.Y, point.Z), Quaternion.identity);
        sphere.name = name;
    }

}

Can you reduce the points? E.g. with only 3 points it will be way easier to figure out what exactly is off .. (scale, orientation (e.g. Y vs Z up), left-handed vs right-handed coordinates, etc)

This question seems to be related to your other question.

@derHugo They are offested a lot. But basically is my approach of using SVD is appropriate ?

idk .. but just by looking on your first graphic .. the positive Y axis goes down (in Unity up) and is somewhere centered (is your Unity world centered at the same spot?) .. to me it looks somewhat upsidedown, shifted diagonal and scaled too small

@derHugo You are correct, I fixed these small coordinate systems problems. But still the alignment doesn't occur. does icp to work, or  SVD, each point should have a corresponding point ?from source and target ? a stupid case, if source has 3 point sand target has 9 points and I would like to align those 3 points onto the 9
but those 3 has 3 corresponding from the 9 points
